# How can I see a list of my unrated apps?

Tags: google-play-store, app-ratings

It's important to me to provide feedback on the apps I use.
However, I don't remember which apps I already rated, and I find myself checking my apps one by one to find the ones I haven't rated yet.

Is there a way to see a list of my unrated apps?

<sup>I have a Galaxy S2 with ICS, but I think this question is relevant to all Android devices.</sup>

Comment: This will give you a list of all apps per device, but no rating info: https://play.google.com/apps

Answer (score 3):

You cannot currently get that list.

You may want to temporarily:

- Disable **Auto-update Apps** in the Google Play **Settings** menu on your device.
- Enable the **Notifications** checkbox.
- Choose when to update each app manually, once you see an update notification. Your existing review, or lack of review, is evident right there 1 inch down the app page if you are in in portrait mode.
- Two weeks later, you'll have reviewed those developers who are updating super-regularly. Keep this up for as long as you can stand to, and all of the developers who aren't dormant are reviewed. Then switch your settings back.

Each manual update will occupy about 30 seconds per app of your time, or less. And it's not perfect. There will be apps who never update before you decide to re-enable **Auto-update Apps**.

I stay in perpetual Manual update mode and I've never failed to give feedback on any app I've installed.

Answer (score 2):

Create a list in your office/organizer of all your apps, then, as you rate your apps go back to that list and mark them as rated. I know it's not automatically calculated for you thus not super convenient but hey, it has to be better than searching one by one. :-)

Comment: Yeah it's better than searching one by one, but still not good enough. Until there is a better solution, I rather do neither.